# sending headers using $resource in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I want to send headers each time for CRUD operation from factory side.
Here is my factory

```
var appangular.module("LifeStyleFactModule",["ngResource"]);
 app.constant("RES_URL", "http://localhost:9090/")
app.factory("CategoryFactory",function($resource,RES_URL){
var categoryinfo;
var categoryresource=$resource(RES_URL+"category/:id",{"id":"@id"},{update:{method:"PUT"}});
return{
    getcategory:function(){
        categoryinfo=categoryresource.query();
        return categoryinfo;
    },
     addcategoryItem:function(categoryItem){

        var category = new categoryresource(categoryItem);
        category.$save(function(respdata){

            categoryinfo.push(respdata);

        },function(respdata){
        });
    },
    deletecategoryItem:function(idx,id){
        var category=new categoryresource({"id":id});
        category.$delete(function(){
            categoryinfo.splice(idx,1);
        },function(){
        })
    },
    updatecategoryItem:function(categoryItem,idx){
        var category=new categoryresource(categoryItem);
        category.$update({"id":categoryItem._id},function(data){
             categoryinfo[idx]=data;
        },function(){
        })
    }
}
})
```

the above functionality is working well. Now i want to send the token in the headers. How can i do that.

I have tried to do it by the following way

```
var categoryresource=$resource(RES_URL+"category/:id",{"id":"@id"},{update:{method:"PUT"},headers:{"token":"@token}});
```

but not getting how to send the token for CRUD operation.

Is procedure is correct, if so how can i send tokens.

Else let me know the way.

Instead of above method i tried the following way as

```
 $resource(RES_URL+"category",{},{query:{method:"get",isArray:true,headers:{"token":token}}}).query({},function(res){});
```

this is working but the procedure for the first procedure.

Please after answering mark it as duplicate or down vote

dont say ( / { such things are missing.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution as to me is to use interceptor. Here is a way to send token in headers, I've used in one of my projects.

```
angular
  .module('app.core')
  .config(config);

config.$inject = ['$httpProvider'];

function config($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
}

interceptor.$inject = ['$q', '$injector', 'AuthModel'];

function interceptor($q, $injector, AuthModel) {
  return {
    request: function (config) {
      config.headers.Authorization = AuthModel.token;
      return config;
    },
    responseError: function (rejection) {

    }
  };

}
```

Added a jsfiddle to demonstrate

https://jsfiddle.net/Sergey_Mell/c47js1zc/

Just click the **Send button** and check the request headers in developer tools

Comment: @Sergrey can u provide me a fiddle of it.

Comment: Here it is
https://jsfiddle.net/Sergey_Mell/c47js1zc/
Click on the *send request* button and see the request headers in the Developers tool

Comment: @ANK, did this helped?

Comment: I have a question here that, whether we need to send the token with each API manually or just once assigned to interceptor it will take care of all API like save, delete, update, get as for each api i am sending token in the headers with resource

Comment: Interceptor will take care of all http requests

Comment: That's ok but each time the user login it create new token, how to send that token that is Authmodel. we have to send it from config..? How..?

Comment: Store the token in AuthModel field and it will always be up to date. I don't see any problem here

Comment: K i will try for it.